# @ethereumjs/tx - "TypeError: Common is not a constructor"

Tags: web3js, blockchain, ethereumjs, eip-1559

I was trying to implement a method for signing an eip-1559 transaction using `@ethereumjs/tx` package. While following the steps mentioned in their [documentation](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/tree/master/packages/tx#gas-fee-market-transactions-eip-1559) , I am encountering an error when trying to initialize the class `Common` of the `@ethereumjs/common` package.

**Method :**

```
const { FeeMarketEIP1559Transaction } = require('@ethereumjs/tx');
const Common = require('@ethereumjs/common');
const { Chain, Hardfork } = require('@ethereumjs/common');

async function signTx(to, from, value, gasLimit, nonce) {
    const privateKey = 'private_key'

    const rawTx = { to, from, value, gasLimit, data: '0x00', nonce }

    const pkey = Buffer.from(privateKey, 'hex'); 

    const common =  new Common({ chain: Chain.Ropsten, hardfork: Hardfork.London });

    const tx = FeeMarketEIP1559Transaction.fromTxData(rawTx, { common })

    tx.sign(pkey);

    const signedTx = `0x${tx.serialize().toString('hex')}`;

    return signedTx;
}
```

**Error :**
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Common is not a constructor`

**Package versions :**

- `@ethereumjs/common` : `2.4.0`
- `@ethereumjs/tx`: `3.3.0`

Any help on this would be highly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved.

`@ethereumjs/common` should be imported as `default` like below.

`const Common = require('@ethereumjs/common').default;`

Comment: This is for CommonJs, how to use the lib in ES?

Comment: @Gutyn Can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using import statement a workaround looks like this :

```
import {default as common} from '@ethereumjs/common';
const Common = common.default

const c = new Common({ chain: Chain.Mainnet, hardfork: Hardfork.London })
```